# Any resource for getting comprehensive browser CSS properties?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, browser

I would love to be able to see a simple list of every CSS property a given browser supports (the browser I need to especially read about it IE8..). Any thoughts on where to find such a list(s)?

Comment: Open IE8 to any page, press F12 select an element and view the style tab/CSS properties (it can show only those set and all defaults)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mozilla Developer Network has the best CSS documentation in my opinion:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference

Answer (score 1):

["Can I use" (caniuse.com)](http://caniuse.com/) is a good start, but it's organized by property, not by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete list of CSS properties: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp If there is a specific property you want to find the compatability for, just click on it and read "Browser Support" section.

For a list of CSS3 and HTML5 features I like this site as well: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/ as it will allow you to quickly identify a specific feature. Although it's not as comprehensive as the w3 schools reference.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) page in quirksmode.org has a nice breakdown by browser.

Answer (score 0):

There’s [CSS reference information by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/ms531209.aspx), describing CSS as recognized by various versions of IE.

There’s a also [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which focuses on describing what features of CSS3 have been implemented in IE. So it does not describe vendor−specific features.